# YAML python array object order

Tags: python, yaml, python-2.x

I'm trying to figure out a way to preserve the order in my yaml? when I iterate the dictionary I get back my order is wrong.

```
from yaml import load

def __init__(self, logger, configFilePath):
    self.config_dict = None

    with open(configFilePath) as config:
        self.config_dict = load(config)

    logger.debug('values:')  
    for key, value in self.config_dict.iteritems():
        logger.debug('- ' + key + ': ' + str(value))

    logger.debug('+++ Successfully finished +++')

def getConfig(self):
    return self.config_dict
```

Yaml example

```
    repos.images:
      -
       id: Thing1
       foo: bar 
       name: Sam
      -
       id: thing2
       foo: bar
       name: dan
```

here is an example of how I'm calling the class. Its nothing really fancy. in a nutshell rather than getting thing1 first I get thing2 first...

```
yamlObj = parser.config_parser(logger, theFile)
myYaml = yamlObj.getConfig()
for image in myYaml["repos.images"]:
    myStr = image["foo"] + '/' + image["id"]
    logger.debug("myStr is: " + myStr)
```

is there a way to do this or is there a better way I could structure my yaml?

Comment: Please include a yaml example that matches your code.  Looking at your logic, it's clear that you're not iterating over the yaml you show.  Why do that to us?

Comment: sorry was trying to keep it simple. I've updated it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries ( or hashes, key/value, associative arrays, maps, call them what you will ) are typically explicitly unordered.  If you really want the order to be maintained, you might be able to make that happen with a different yaml library ( at work we've used https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml to make "in-place" updates to yaml files).

But make sure to also use an ordered dictionary (python3) or other solution for the data once it's pulled out of YaML.

Comment: on python 2.7 unfortunately and I'd rather not have to go through switching libraries.  I read somewhere I could try  `!!omap` but no dice yet.

Comment: On one hand it's a good point about dicts, they maintain oder (not guaranteed, though) only after Python version 3.6.
In your case, once you've loaded your yaml it is a dictionary with the value that is a list of dicts, so lists are ordered, meaning that the entry that has thing1 attribute should always come first, provided it's first in the yaml file. Or are you concerned about keys 'id', 'foo' and 'name' appearing at a different order?

Comment: yes the attributes within the each object is ordered. It's ordering in `-` thats causing me a problem because I have one object of the array/list that needs to happen first but it drops to like 3rd.

Comment: I don't understand why though.  Unlike dictionaries, lists are ordered data structures in yaml and Python.

Comment: It is still unclear what is the exact issue. In the question you say that `thing2` comes first, but this cannot happen, since `thing1` comes first in the list (`-` in your yaml file). What would be different is the order of inner keys (`id`, `foo`, `name`) between executions, but within the elements of the list it would still be the same. It shouldn't be a problem though, because once you iterate over your list of dicts, you access the values based on `key` identifier, not an index.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `namedtuple` to have some control over your loaded configuration. Also, consider using `safe_load`

```
import collections
import yaml


file = open("./so.yaml", 'r')
cfg = yaml.safe_load(file)

Config = collections.namedtuple("Config", ["id", "foo", "name"])

cfg_lst = [Config(**x) for x in cfg["repos.images"]]
```

Then, for example,

```
>>> print(cfg_lst)
```

would give you

```
>>> [Config(id='Thing1', foo='bar', name='Sam'), Config(id='thing2', foo='bar', name='dan')]
```

So, to access a particular element, say, `thing2`, you'll get to it like this

```
>>> print(cfg_lst[1].id)
>>> thing2
```

Comment: without `safe_load`, yaml is frighteningly insecure.  https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation says, "It is not safe to call yaml.load with any data received from an untrusted source... [it] may call any Python function. "

Answer (score 1):

I've recently written a library for this, [`oyaml`](https://github.com/wimglenn/oyaml).  At the shell:

```
$ pip install oyaml
```

In your Python code, it is a one character change:

```
from oyaml import load  # instead of `from yaml import load`
```

Then mappings will be loaded into [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instances instead of regular dicts, preserving their original ordering from the config file.